# loop through a row and merge cells as header vba

Tags: vba, excel

This is an addition to my question yesterday so I am starting a new question. Basically I get different ranges of data on a sheet in excel and data range vary each week so last used column and last used row vary.

I would like to merge row 3 and 4 based on names and I will post a sample data so you can understand what I am trying to achieve. Row 3 is the one that has the names and row 4 is always empty. Right now, I am getting `error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set` on Loop While that line.

And again, I am only showing you 3 ranges since it is best fit on the picture.

```
Sub test()

'Set Up

Dim f, g, h, i, j, k As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet



Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")




'Merge back
With ws1.Rows(3)
    Set f = .Find("A", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = f.Address
        Do
           Range(f.Resize(2), f.Resize(, 1)).Merge
           Range(f.Resize(2), f.End(xlToRight)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
           Set f = .FindNext(f)

        Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End With

With ws1.Rows(3)
    Set g = .Find("B", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not g Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = g.Address
        Do
           Range(g.Resize(2), g.Resize(, 1)).Merge
           Range(g.Resize(2), g.End(xlToRight)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
            Set g = .FindNext(g)
        Loop While Not g Is Nothing And g.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End With


With ws1.Rows(3)
    Set h = .Find("C", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not h Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = h.Address
        Do
           Range(h.Resize(2), h.Resize(, 1)).Merge
           Range(h.Resize(2), h.End(xlToRight)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
            Set g = .FindNext(h)
        Loop While Not h Is Nothing And h.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End With


With ws1.Rows(3)
    Set i = .Find("D", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = i.Address
        Do
           Range(i.Resize(2), i.Resize(, 1)).Merge
            Set i = .FindNext(i)
        Loop While Not i Is Nothing And i.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End With

With ws1.Rows(3)
    Set j = .Find("E", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not j Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = j.Address
        Do
           Range(j.Resize(2), j.Resize(, 1)).Merge
           Range(j.Resize(2), j.End(xlToRight)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
            Set j = .FindNext(j)
        Loop While Not j Is Nothing And j.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End With


With ws1.Rows(3)
    Set k = .Find("F", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not k Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = k.Address
        Do
           Range(k.Resize(2), k.Resize(, 1)).Merge
            Set k = .FindNext(k)
        Loop While Not k Is Nothing And k.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
End With


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have many Loop While lines. On which does it error?

Comment: it failed at the first one so i assume it will fail at other ones as it loops through it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to match on the letter if you merge always two rows in the same column? You can find first and last used column and loop row 3, if not blank then merge cell and cell.offset(1,0) so to speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this. I think you can shorten your code with a loop. The error I think is caused by the merging of cells which screws up the Find. Merged cells are a bad idea for many reasons.

```
Sub test()

'Set Up
Dim f As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim v, i As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
v = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

'Merge back
For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    With ws1.Rows(3)
        Set f = .Find(v(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstaddress = f.Address
            Do
                f.Resize(2).Merge
                Range(f.Resize(2), f.End(xlToRight)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While Not f Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than resize after the merge, maybe .mergearea would be a better range reference. This will also crash on the rare occasion that it is used in a worksheet's private codesheet when the worksheet is not sheet1. Should be .range not range.

Comment: @Jeeped - do you mean `f.MergeArea.BorderAround`? In the example certainly looks like the End to right is not needed.

Comment: Thanks SJR, I tweaked your codes a bit so a-f are merged one cell down and c,d & e,f have border themselves. Thanks again, your codes were extremely helpful.

Comment: My pleasure. I see now that the borders are not consistent - you could still handle that with a loop depending on how many items you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

A loop from ASCII character 65 (e.g. A) through ASCII character 90 (e.g. Z) should clean up your code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim c As Long, firstaddress As String, f As Range, ffs As Range

    With Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(3).Cells
        .Resize(2, .Columns.Count).UnMerge
        Set f = Nothing
        For c = 65 To 90
            Set f = .Find(Chr(c), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Set ffs = f
                firstaddress = f.Address
                Do
                    Set ffs = Union(f, ffs)
                    Set f = .FindNext(after:=f)
                Loop While f.Address <> firstaddress
                With Union(ffs, ffs.Offset(1))
                    .Merge
                    .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```